# Automating deployment in grunt-backstopjs with commits accept / reject if test is passed / failed

Tags: gruntjs, automated-tests, regression-testing, backstop.js

It seems to be good practice using backstopjs with grunt. Only one thing i want to know is, whether is it possible to create a test script for xyz project and while deploying that project to repository. the backstop test must be run and if there is any failure in test, then that commit should be rejected from deployment and if the test result is passed(100%) than that commit should get deployed to that repository.